# "pecl install memcached" fails

Tags: php, memcached, pecl

I am trying to execute `pecl install memcached`. I am on Mac with PHP 7.4.3

I get the following error

```
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-libmemcached-dir --with-zlib-dir --with-system-fastlz --enable-memcached-igbinary=yes --enable-memcached-msgpack=yes --enable-memcached-json=yes --enable-memcached-protocol=yes --enable-memcached-sasl=yes --enable-memcached-session=yes' failed
```

What am I doing wrong? I get the same error if I say no to prompts.

Comment: Try `sudo pecl install memcached`.

Comment: See this article https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-memcache-extension/